# Eclipse visual indication of edited line

Tags: eclipse

I have used Eclipse for a very long time.  It has its problems, but I always seem to come back to it.

I used IntelliJ a couple of years ago because the client required it.  One of the small things I liked about IntelliJ is that it showed a visual indicator in the gutter if a line had been edited since the last commit.  I would really like to see this in Eclipse.

Am I missing the obvious?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This feature is called *Quick Diff* in Eclipse.

Turn on and configure *Quick Diff*:

1. Click Window > Preferences.
2. In General > Editors > Text Editors > Quick Diff, check **Enable quick diff**.
3. You can also configure the reference source to be the filesystem or, if you have CVS or SVN integration, you can choose one of those as well.

Comment: You don't need to activate line numbers for quick diff to work.

Comment: Wow, thanks, I never knew about this and I have been using Eclipse for ages.